# Yahoo webmail and mailto links

Tags: html, email, mailto, webmail, yahoo-mail

It seems that Yahoo doesn't fill in the information contained within mailto links like other mail clients do.  I'm asking here to see if anyone knows a work-around for Yahoo.

Given this html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="mailto:me@somewhere.com?subject=Hello%20People&bcc=somebcc@example.com">Send Mail</a>
</body>
</head>
```

Can you successfully click the mailto link, Send Mail, and have yahoo open the webmail client AND fill in the meta data?

I am using the Chrome mailto extension to allow me to open webmail in my client of choice, and have selected Yahoo. So that part is working fine...

Some griping I've found on the web: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=513780 re: yahoo and mailto links...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your code.  Handling of any parameters is up to the `mailto:` handler... that extension you're using.

You can't force that `mailto:` handler to do something it isn't built to do.

Comment: It could be the extension. But if it works everywhere else and not yahoo...I'd like to know if other people have successfully used mailto links in conjunction with Yahoo webmail and have had success?